# I try get the current location using below code it works on 6.0–6.0.1 and app crashed in 5.0 and 7.0

Tags: android

In my app I need the current location to find near by ATM's. I used gms to find the current location with run time permission  it works on 6.0–6.0.1 and 5.0. the problem is in 7.0 Samsung and 5.1 version app closed. I put the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` permission in android manifest.  I use the target sdk version 25.

```
   @Override
    public void onLocationReceived(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            address=new FetchAddress(RegisterActivity.this,latLng);
            Log.e("My Address",address.getAddress());
            Log.e("My Locality",address.getLocality());
            tracker1.stopLocationUpdates();
        }

    }
```

Comment: did you add run time permission

Comment: does the location settings on the devices on battery saving mode or high accuracy? Try to change them to high accuracy and then check

Comment: show error logs

Answer (score 0):

Hey your question clearly stated that you haven't write else part of your permission.

1. You might gave permission for marshmallow like

   ```
   if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //after success you call some method
       getLocation();

   }
   ```
2. This function will Invoke only In marshmallow
3. You must write Else part of your permission like below

   ```
       if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //after success you call some method
       getLocation();
       dependentData(); //Main function

       }else
       {
          dependentData(); // If Is > 6 or < 5.0 no matter this should be executed
       }
   ```

try this hope its works.

Comment: She said that code is working in Marshmallow and Lower but not in Nougat. So this answer doesn't fit here.

Comment: Thank you for response. There is have any other solution to rectify the problem.